# Remove Graphics card driver?

Tags: debian, nvidia, graphics, steam

Okay, I have looked at many posts and threads and haven't found a solution.
So I am running x64 Debian. I installed Nvidia drivers from Nvidia's website by running a .run file. Now, I tried to install Steam so I tried

```
Sudo apt install steam
```

I even tried hitting [TAB] after to see if it had a different name but it was nowhere to be found. So I downloaded a .deb file from the website and tried running it with

```
Sudo dpkg -i steam_latest.deb
```

but it installed and gave me an error:

```
Failed to parse arguments: Option "--disable-factory" is no longer supported in this version of gnome-terminal.
Package libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 needs to be installed
Package libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 needs to be installed
Running Steam on debian 9 64-bit
STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled automatically
Pins up-to-date!
Error: You are missing the following 32-bit libraries, and Steam may not run:
libGL.so.1
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1509425745)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1509425745)   
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1509425745)
Failed to load steamui.so - dlerror(): libGL.so.1: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1509425745)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1509425745)
[2017-11-15 10:42:19] Startup - updater built Oct 30 2017 19:09:32
Looks like steam didn't shutdown cleanly, scheduling immediate update check
[2017-11-15 10:42:19] Checking for update on startup
[2017-11-15 10:42:19] Checking for available updates...
[2017-11-15 10:42:19] Download skipped: /client/steam_client_ubuntu12 version 1509425745, installed version 1509425745
[2017-11-15 10:42:19] Nothing to do
[2017-11-15 10:42:19] Verifying installation...
[2017-11-15 10:42:19] Performing checksum verification of executable files
[2017-11-15 10:42:19] Verification complete
[2017-11-15 10:42:22] Shutdown
```

So it wouldn't run. I have TeamViewer installed which is also an i836 app and it runs so I don't think it is a problem with Multiarch. I asked on Reddit and a guy said it was probably a graphics card driver error so I tried to

```
sudo apt install nvidia-driver
```

Which was found but it game me this error

```
E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem.
```

Naturally, I tried "sudo dpkg --configure -a" but I get this

```
Setting up nvidia-installer-cleanup (20151021+4) ...

WARNING: The '--no-runlevel-check' option is deprecated:  nvidia-installer will
     ignore this option.


Welcome to the NVIDIA Software Installer for Unix/Linux

Detected 8 CPUs online; setting concurrency level to 8.

If you plan to no longer use the NVIDIA driver, you should make sure that no X
screens are configured to use the NVIDIA X driver in your X configuration file.
If you used nvidia-xconfig to configure X, it may have created a backup of your
original configuration. Would you like to run `nvidia-xconfig
--restore-original-backup` to attempt restoration of the original X
configuration file?
  [default: (N)o]:
```

Then I type y and hit enter and it freezes. even after an hour it is not done and the progress bar that pops up doesn't move. Is it my graphics? How can I completely remove everything and reinstall to start from the begining of just my graphics card drivers without reinstalling my OS?

This is the output of "glxinfo | grep render"

```
direct rendering: Yes
OpenGL renderer string: GeForce GTX 1060/PCIe/SSE2
    GL_ARB_conditional_render_inverted, GL_ARB_conservative_depth, 
    GL_NVX_conditional_render, GL_NVX_gpu_memory_info, 
    GL_NVX_nvenc_interop, 
    GL_NV_compute_program5, GL_NV_conditional_render, 
    GL_NV_parameter_buffer_object2, GL_NV_path_rendering, 
    GL_NV_path_rendering_shared_edge, GL_NV_pixel_data_range, 
    GL_NV_shader_thread_shuffle, GL_NV_stereo_view_rendering, 
    GL_ARB_compute_variable_group_size, GL_ARB_conditional_render_inverted, 
    GL_NVX_conditional_render, GL_NVX_gpu_memory_info, GL_NVX_nvenc_interop, 
    GL_NV_compute_program5, GL_NV_conditional_render, 
    GL_NV_parameter_buffer_object2, GL_NV_path_rendering, 
    GL_NV_path_rendering_shared_edge, GL_NV_pixel_data_range, 
    GL_NV_shader_thread_shuffle, GL_NV_stereo_view_rendering, 
    GL_EXT_raster_multisample, GL_EXT_render_snorm, GL_EXT_robustness, 
    GL_NV_conditional_render, GL_NV_conservative_raster, 
    GL_NV_packed_float_linear, GL_NV_path_rendering, 
    GL_NV_path_rendering_shared_edge, GL_NV_pixel_buffer_object, 
    GL_NV_stereo_view_rendering, GL_NV_texture_array, GL_NV_texture_barrier, 
    GL_OES_fbo_render_mipmap, GL_OES_geometry_point_size,
```

Comment: Does TeamViewer use direct rendering ? I doubt it. You are missing direct rendering support for i386. Have you tried installing the two packages steam said were missing ( libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 and libgl1-mesa-glx:i386) ? Also, what is the output of `glxinfo | grep render` ?

Comment: It was too big for a comment I am pasting it in as an edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will first attempt to explain what was happening, to the best of my knowledge ;-). Then provide a few user-friendly tips for Debian users.

Why did you initial command not work ?

```
Sudo apt install Steam
```

The package is actually called "steam" (all lower case), it is a i386 package, so to install it, you issue the following:

```
sudo apt-get install steam:i386
```

This should have, in theory, pulled all dependencies and all should have been fine.

How do I know, I do not have steam installed ? Google ;-)

To find a package in Debian, the easiest and friendliest I found is the following Google search:

```
<package> site:packages.debian.org
```

In this case:

```
Steam site:packages.debian.org
```

This is one result: "https://packages.debian.org/stretch/steam", on the top I can see in which repository it is (non-free), on the bottom of that page, I can see for which architectures steam is available, namely, "i386" only.

```
Package libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 needs to be installed 
Package libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 needs to be installed 
Running Steam on debian 9
64-bit STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled automatically Pins up-to-date! Error:
You are missing the following 32-bit libraries, and Steam may not run:
libGL.so.1
```

Here, apt is telling you that steam needs `libgl1-mesa-dri:i386` and `libgl1-mesa-glx:i386` and later, it is also telling you exactly which library is needed:

`libGL.so.1`

Again,  how would I easily find out how to install that library ? Google, again, is your friend:

```
libGL.so.1 site:packages.debian.org
```

I click on one of the results and I see `libGL.so.1` is provided by:

```
libgl1-mesa-glx:i386
```

Actually, I did not have to google as I know `libgl1` (in the package name) is libGL.so.1, but that was just a bit lucky.

Now, apt is smart, that is exactly the package apt complained about was missing ;-).

> How can I completely remove everything and reinstall to start from the
>   begining of just my graphics card drivers without reinstalling my OS?

First of all, you need to prepare a text file with the commands you want to execute because we are going to use the console.

Place the following in a text file, store it in your home directory in a file called `mycommands.txt`:

```
sudo apt-get remove steam
sudo service gdm3 stop
sudo nvidia-uninstall
sudo apt-get install nvidia-driver
sudo apt-get install steam
echo done
```

Hit `Ctrl+Alt+F2`, you should now be on tty2, enter your username and password.
Next, we `source` our text file to execute the commands (it will ask for your `sudo` password):

```
. mycommands.txt
```

Notice the dot (important). If you placed the file on your desktop, for example, you would have to issue:

```
. ~/Desktop/mycommands.txt
```

Accept the Steam license, all should be fine, I hope.

Comment: Thanks, I did not capitalize steam when I did the search I just accidentally did when I put it in here. I tried making and running your script but it still froze at the same spot. So it never got past nvidia-uninstall. I did run that in tty2

Comment: I ran it in recovery mode and it is fixed now. Thank you so much!!!

Answer (score 0):

It is probably some graphic card versions do not supported. Like mine 820M. I am using Nouveau instead of nvidia and it works fine most of the games and apps.

Comment: That might be the case. How can I change it so I can test it?